# Access USB device info with ctypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, kernel, ctypes

I am using python with `ctypes` to somehow access information about a USB device that is connected to the PC. Is this achievable from a .dll? I try to find things like where it's mounted, its vendor, etc.

An example:

```
>>> import ctypes import windll
>>> windll.kernel32
<WindDLL 'kernel32', handle 77590000 at 581b70>
```

But how do I find which .dll is the right one? I googled around but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Comment: Winusb.ddl : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926923/winusb-dll-and-python-specifically-winusb-initialize

Answer (score 2):

In the end I used a simpler methodology.

I use the `winreg` module that ships with Python to get access to the Windows registry. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` keeps track of all devices mounted (currently connected or not). So I get all the device information from there and to check if the device is currently connected I simply `os.path.exists` the storage letter of the device (ie. `G:`). The storage letter can be obtained from the key `MountedDevices`.

Example:

```
# Make it work for Python2 and Python3
if sys.version_info[0]<3:
    from _winreg import *
else:
    from winreg import *

# Get DOS devices (connected or not)
def get_dos_devices():
    ddevs=[dev for dev in get_mounted_devices() if 'DosDevices' in dev[0]]
    return [(d[0], regbin2str(d[1])) for d in ddevs]

# Get all mounted devices (connected or not)
def get_mounted_devices():
    devs=[]
    mounts=OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\MountedDevices')
    for i in range(QueryInfoKey(mounts)[1]):
        devs+=[EnumValue(mounts, i)]
    return devs

# Decode registry binary to readable string
def regbin2str(bin):
    str=''
    for i in range(0, len(bin), 2):
        if bin[i]<128:
            str+=chr(bin[i])
    return str
```

Then simply run:

```
get_dos_devices()
```